# XBee wireless module not responding any more

Tags: wireless, uart, rs232, xbee, configuration

I bought an XBee-PRO S1 .. I built its  serial explorer to be able to configure it through the PC, I’m using X-CTU to  configure and test it at first it worked well,I made test/query successfully  many times I tried to write a modem configuration to it .. but each time ended  with a failed message, through this the chip was still responding to the  test/query, and the terminal command "+++", but trying to configure it 3 or 4  more times it stopped responding, well, I figured I was wrongly configuring it,  as I didn't use the reset to reset the chip before writing the new configuration  to it .. then i fixed my explorer circuit, and tried using a reset button, it  worked one or two times, and a progress bar appeared, but the process failed too  .. now the XBee isn't responding any more for any of what I did before .. I searched, and found many people facing the same problem ..

This problem happened with two modules in row .....

In short “I write +++ it responds OK , If started to  configure say AT..anything , It stops & no respond , if I tried “+++” again  .. no respond , it’s even not recognized by the X-CTU” ...

I hope  I can find help about what should I do to recover this XBee, and what mistakes  did I do so I can avoid them in future .........

**Update #1:-**

I contacted the manufacture digi(dot).com

Support: 
In order to change the  firmware on the radio, the DTR and RTS lines are required. To resolve your  issue, I would recommend either acquire one of our XBIB interface boars or you  follow the steps outlined at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxOqQZD-oaM  once the DTR and RTS lines are connected using the proper level  shifting.

As described in the  product manual, the radio is a 3V device and is NOT 5V or RS232 level tolerant.  You need to use a level shifter between the radio and the PC or some other Non  3V CMOS level device. Otherwise you will damage the  module.

You  can see a sample schematic of our XBIB interface boards buy going to http://www.digi.com/support/kbase/kbaseresultdetl?id=2118.  However if you are not familiar with level shifting, I would strongly recommend  acquiring one of our XBIB development boards as it will give you a known  starting point to work from.

**Me after the update :**

Of course nothing worked from the support !

The behavior I noticed that :-

When I press the reset for a while (4 ~5 ) seconds , the CTS line in XCTU is lighted up(Green) ..... So ?

Comment: What kind of ranges are you wanting to transmit data over?

Comment: @sptrks
do you mean the frequency range ? .. 2.4 GHz .. as it is a free frequency for developing ..
i also need it to transmit with a minimum radius 60 m

Comment: @mina_g before your support ticket, were applying 5V signaling directly to the module without level shifting it to 3V signaling? If so you may have done permanent damage.

Comment: @vicatcu No, the VCC of the max232 is on 3.3 V (accurately 3.16 v), i measured its outputs going to the XBee, they are from 0 to 3.16 V

Comment: after searching more, i think that my XBee bootloader is broken .. anyone has a solution or confirmation for this ?!

Answer (score 2):

I've just made an instructable for this problem.  I have not proven them to work with Series 1 XBees yet, but this should be the same solution for each Series one and two.  Try it and let me know the results!  http://www.instructables.com/id/Restoring-your-broken-XBee/